# Strange confirmation page after redirect of Web 2 Lead

Tags: web2lead

Since today in production when I use a web-to-lead form the user click "submit" goes to salesforce, and, instead of being submitted back immediately, a white page with "you'll be redirected to ... clikc OK" appears.

If I use the web-to-lead in sandbox it doesn't appear. Is there some way of turning it off?

Is it some sort of way of saying salesforce don't want to offer web-to-lead anymore? No clients that I know would use it as it is now:(

Comment: That is the URL that is showing the redirection message?

Comment: Yes, I'm working it around creating a fake form in javascript which targets a non-visible iframe so that the crazy page stays there (but another fun fact, mozilla firefox neglects users from landing on salesforce.com by default as it is a user tracking domain)

Comment: SFDC Web 2 Lead is still supported.

Comment: @T.Rossi Sorry, I meant to say, **What** is the URL that is showing the redirection message? Is it something from a Salesforce domain?

Comment: the retURL is a page on the domain of the client, something like: http://somedomain.com/thankyoupage . I've prepared a javascript to hide the submit into an hidden iframe in order not to show that confirmation page, but I am wondering if that confirmation page can be turned off.